# CSS hover slow on IE9

Tags: css, performance, hover, internet-explorer-9

I'm working on a site where the frontpage works fine in most browsers (Chrome, FF, IE8), however checking it in IE9 revealed that the page is very slow. I think the css hover I use on the thumbnails is causing this. However I'm not 100% sure.

Things tried
- Disabled all plugins, no change
- Used a transparent png instead, no change
- Used jQuery to achieve the effect, no change
- Used in page Javacript, no change
- Tried playing with removing heights/widths (following some other discussions here), no change

The site in question: http://funslots.eu

Is the css hover indeed causing this or am I missing something else?

Comment: not sure what must be causing this, but can you tell me what are you using for opacity in IE9 ?

Comment: Hi, I'm not using anything special for opacity in IE9, afaik the normal css opacity command should work in IE9. (removed the filter command some time back, because it gave some other troubles).

Comment: Btw, I'm using css pie for the rounded corners for IE8 and below. Just tried it with removing all references to css pie, but unfortunately that didn't make a difference. :(

Comment: Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?